# Can I suppress the authentication dialog in a Cocoa WebView?

Tags: cocoa, webview

I'm using a Cocoa WebView object and I'd like to suppress the authentication dialog that pops down when the user types in the wrong credentials. The server is sending back a Www-Authenticate response header which I believe is triggering the dialog.

Can I somehow intercept this header before it triggers the authentication challenge? Or is there some other way to disable the challenge dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`WebResourceLoadDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebResourceLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/WebResourceLoadDelegate). It has a method `webView:resource:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:fromDataSource:` that you can implement to intercept those WWW-Authenticate responses. Just make sure you call `setResourceLoadDelegate:` on your `WebView` to give it your delegate class where that method is implemented.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I see that method, but I don't know what to do to actually disable the dialog.

Comment: Ok, so what I did was I implemented the method and then canceled the challenge with:
[[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge] and that seems to work.

Comment: Excellent. =) I'm glad that helped you find the solution you needed.